# How to extend SMSC of any Mobile Service Provider?

Tags: java, sms-gateway

We want to create an application that can integrate with any SMSC(short message service center) and perform the following.
We have the following use case:

1. Mobile user sends sms to her friend
2. Message get routed to SMSC message server
3. Message server checks for bad content, words, threats(words that not suit to a particular community)...The pattern of these words will be defined later.
4. If the sms contains bad content, the SMSC message server sends notification to administrator device(it might be a mobile phone, computer, e.t.c), then delete the message from message server.
5. If the sms is good(no bad content), SMSC routes message to intended receipt.
6. End

I just want to know if it is possible to get SMSC API that allows implementation of a function(s) that can fulfill the use case above.
Any SMSC API will be appreciated.

We are at initial stages of oure research project.

Comment: Questions looking for tools or libraries that fulfil a certain task are generally off topic on SO. Check the [help] for more info. I'm voting to close this question as as result.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the Open Source Mobicents SMSC server, which supports SMPP, SIP and SS7/SIGTRAN interfaces, as well as HTTP REST APIs via Restcomm.

In fact you may want to consider promptly building the SMS handling logic with the Restcomm Visual Designer and use the External Service feature to integrate with the rest of your business logic.

https://code.google.com/p/smscgateway/ http://www.restcomm.com/

Comment: Hi Ivelin, we ae looking to build an SMSC router using 3GPP specifications or Restcomm MAP. It seems you maybe having some knowledge using the same. Please let me know if interested.

Answer (score -1):

yeah, it possible. just subscribe for a bulksms service